# Product of product-measurable function and measurable function product-measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Given two measurable spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}), (\Theta, \mathcal{F}_\Theta)$ and their product with the product-sigma-algebra $(\Omega \times \Theta, \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}_\Theta)$ and two functions $f, g$ with $f: \Omega \times \Theta \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})})$ and $g: \Theta \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})})$. Function f is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}_\Theta$ and g is measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_\Theta$

Now is the product of the two functions, $f \cdot g $, measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{F}_\Theta$?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: is $g$ itself measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra? If so then you are done, because products of measurable functions are measurable.

Comment: If we consider $g$ as a mapping from the product space, constant in the first argument, $g^{-1}(B) = \Omega \times T$ for some $T \in  \mathcal{F}_\Theta$ and a Borelset $B$. So I'm done?

Comment: Such a product is in the product $\sigma$-algebra (why?)

Comment: By construction, the product $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra w.r.t. which all projections (from measurable subsets of single involved spaces to their cartesian product)  are measurable.

Comment: Right. That means that any product of two measurable sets is in the product $\sigma$-algebra (these are the generating elements, often called "rectangles").